# Need to find username/password that program uses to write to firebird DB

Tags: passwords, firebird, credentials

I have a program that accesses a local firebird database. It has write access to this database, and we need to be able to write to this database, but do not know the username/password.

Obviously, somewhere in the PC is a connection string/username/password to be able to connect to that database. What methods could I use to find this?

I've tried process monitor to see if it accesses any registry keys but can't see any.
I've checked the installation directories for configuration files.
I've decompiled some of the DAL DLL's but can't see any hardcoding anywhere!

The vendor is no longer, so we can't go to them.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If with "local" you mean embedded then you actually don't need to know the password - the embedded version doesn't check password. Quote from the "README_embedded.txt" file, chapter "2.3. Authentication and security":

> The security database (namely security2.fdb) is not used in the embedded server and hence is not required. Any user is able to attach to any database. Since both the server and the client run in the same address space, the security becomes just an agreement between both sides which can be easily compromised.

So you actually need only the username, and for that you can use `SYSDBA` - the Firebird's superuser. Note that the username is still checked, even with embedded, to assign user SQL privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I ended up working out that it was in fact NOT the embedded version and it did have a SYSDBA password. I used a Java decompiler and was able to find the algorithm that was used to generate the password- popped that into a java project and got me the password! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492821/466862) by *ain* regarding use of embedded, authentication in Firebird is handled by the server and its associated security database. This means that if you copy (or better: backup and restore) a Firebird database to a different server where you know the SYSDBA password, then you can simply access the database.

However if you want continuous write access from a different process to a database that is used by a Firebird server embedded in an user application: you can't. The embedded server (at least on Windows), does not allows external connections.